# Is this proof about the null space and column space correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

My question asks me to show that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $AB=0$, then the column space of $B$ must be a subspace of the nullspace of $A$.

My attempt at a proof is like this:

we have that $$AB=\left [ Ab_{1}, Ab_{2}\, ...\,Ab_{n}\right ]=0$$
In particular $\left \{ \forall i\,|\,0<i\leq n\right \}\,Ab_{i}=0$

Since $Col(B) = span\left\{ b_{i}\right\}$, and $ \forall i\,|\,0<i\leq n \,\, ,b_{i}$ is in the null space of A,  we have shown that the column space of B is a subspace of the null space of A.

I'm pretty sure I have it correct (though I may be wrong) but If you think I should structure it differently or use different notation I am open to suggestions.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The overall logic is essentially sound. I think most instructors would want to see a proof of $\operatorname{Col}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{Null}(A)$ in the form, "Let $X$ be an arbitrary element of $\operatorname{Col}(B)$...". Separately, the expression "$\{\forall i | 0 < i \leq n\}$" reads "The set of for all $i$ such that $0 < i \leq n$", which is grammatically and mathematically anomalous, though the intended meaning is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you, yeah my notation is usually awful :( haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is alright. Perhaps you can make it a bit more explicit. If $AB=0$ and $x \in \mbox{Col}(B)$, then $x$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $B$. But every one of those columns is mapped to $0$ under $A$ (you showed this), so any linear combination is mapped to $0$ as well, so $x \in \mbox{Null}(A)$ too.

Alternative: suppose it's not true and there is a vector $y = Bx$ in the column space of $B$, not in the null space of $A$. But then:
$$Ay = A(Bx) = (AB)x \ne 0$$
which contradicts $AB = 0$.

Comment: thank you! this is really helpful!

Comment: You're welcome!